# About Sharepoint image slider

Tags: javascript, c#, sharepoint-2010

I want   onclick function where I want to display the sharepoint folder content. I write the code and getting all the foldername in link bt when i click on that link its showing all images of folders. I want only that folder images on which i click please help.

Comment: Show your effort so far and explain a specific problem.

Comment: i want to display sharepoint library folder images in slider using visual web part. i used <a href > and nw getting all the folder in that < a hre> bt when i click on that folderlink it display all the images of all folder bt i want only that folder images on which i clicked